# Construct a true type of integer with parameter

Tags: bash

Suppose such a code:

```
    #! /usr/local/bin/bash
    position=1
    echo "Paramter: $1"
```

We can see that type of `1` in `position=1` is a string,
while type of `1` in `"Parameter: $1"` is an integer which positions appropriate argument on command line.

```
    $ bash question.sh test
    Paramter: test
```

When replace 1 in `$1` with `position`, it become a parameter expansion.

```
    position=1
    echo "Paramter: $position"
    # run and output
    $ bash question.sh test
    Parameter: 1
```

However, I insist on substitute it with parameter `position`

```
    position=1
    echo "Parameter: $(($position))"
    #output
    $ bash question.sh test
    Paramter: 1

    position=1
    echo "Parameter: $$(($position))"
    $ bash question.sh test
    Paramter: 34588((1))
```

Failed to achieve my expectation.

Is it possible to construce a true type of integer?

Comment: Is your question how to use integer arithmetic with a variable?

Comment: I want to replace 1 in `$1` with a variable of integer type. @kabanus

Comment: `echo "Parameter: $((position + 1))"`...

Comment: warning: you have a space in shebang et double $$ (normally Pid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation of `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) explains, under the ["Shell Parameter Expansion" section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> The basic form of parameter expansion is `${parameter}` [...]
>
> If the first character of `parameter` is an exclamation point (`!`), it introduces a level of variable indirection. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of `parameter` as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of `parameter` itself. This is known as *indirect expansion*. The exceptions to this are the expansions of `${!prefix*}` and `${!name[@]}` described below. The exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to introduce indirection.

This leads to a simple conclusion. Your script should be like:

```
#!/bin/bash

parameter=1
echo "Parameter #${parameter}: ${!parameter}"
```

Run and output:

```
$ bash question.sh foo bar
Parameter #1: foo
```

---

If you are patient enough, you can read the documentation of any Unix command (`bash` included) in the comfort of your terminal window **:-p**, using the `man` command. Type `man bash` to read the documentation of `man` (it is very long, probably the longest `man` page); the excerpt above has been copied from it.

Comment: Please, really help, especially you address all are string. @kabanus

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as integer type in bash. Just think of everything as a string. Bash does have operators that know how to do arithmetic with strings of integers. What you want if I understand correctly is (contents of `test.bash`):

```
p=1
#Better to space things out in bash!
echo "p: $(( $1 + p ))"
```

Such that:

```
test.bash 2
```

will output

```
3
```

You don't really need the `$` inside `$((...))` for variables, `bash` will interpret a non-integer string as a variable. The special case are script arguments such as `$1`, which must come with a `$`.

Comment: position parameter 1 in `$1` is an integer, since it counts.

Comment: @Tool You seem to be misunderstanding what a **type** in a programming language is. It doesn't matter what meaning you assign to it (such as something that "counts), the language has it's own specification. The `$(())` operator takes strings of numbers, and performs arithmetic on them, but that's the operator handling, not the type.

Comment: `$(( $1 + p ))` is the same as `$(( p + $1 ))`, the order doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @l'L'l Correct, where did you get it does?

Comment: I get your idea, so 1 in `$1` cannot be substitute with any variable we set by ourself. @kabanus